# Rhombus intersected by a triangle, forming a series of isosceles triangles. Use geometric properties to determine unknown angle.

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the diagram shown, the line segments AB, BC, CD and DA are all equal in length; in addition, BE = BD . Lines AED, BEF and CDF are straight. Given that ∠BFD = 33° , find the value of ∠FED ?

- s+t=180°
- $⇒ ∠EDF = 180°- s - 33° = t - 33°$

Contained within the diagram is a rhombus, and a few isosceles triangles. I've marked off the information I can fathom but struggling to form the algebraic relationships to home in on the value of angle 's'.

Any pointers on forming useful algebra in cases like this, without going around in circles?

Based on @Daniel Mathias pointer:

The diagonals of a rhombus bisect each other, so

- $∠ = ∠ =  ⟹ 3−33=180 ⟹ t = 71°$
- $⟹ s = 180 - 71 = 109$
- $∠FED = 109°$

Comment: $\angle BDC = \angle BDA = t \implies 3t-33=180$

Comment: You can find the value of $t$ many ways. $\angle ABF = \angle BFC = 33$ so $(180 - 2t)+ 33 = t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing the unknown value *t* is not needed.

First of all we can label $\angle FED$ as $s$, therefore $\angle BED$ = $180 - s$.

because triangle $BED$ is an isosceles, $\angle BDE$ = $180 - s$ as well.

$⟹$ $\angle DBE = 180 - 2(180 - s) = 2s - 180$

$\angle EFD = 33 ⟹ \angle EBA = 33$ (alternate angles)

$⟹$ $\angle DBA = 2s - 180 + 33 = 2s - 147$

$\angle DBA = \angle ADB (isosceles) ⟹ 2s - 147 = 180 - s, 3s = 327, s = 109$